# Ant execute a command

Tags: ant, exec

I use Silk4J and in my build, I have to start the agent.  The command I use is:

```
<exec spawn="true" executable="${env.OPEN_AGENT_HOME}/agent/openAgent.exe" />
```

It gives me this error

```
The ' characters around the executable and arguments are not part of the command.
```

Do I need to change it?

Answer (score 8):

The message doesn't signify an error.

When the `-v`, `-verbose`, `-d`, or `-debug` option is given to Ant, the `<exec>` task outputs the command it is executing along with the message:

```
 [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
 [exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
 [exec] '/c'
 [exec] '@for %a in (C:\src\ant\ant-dir-file-local) do @echo %~ta'
 [exec]
 [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
 [exec] not part of the command.
 [exec] 10/23/2013 02:36 AM
```

Breaking down the above example...

```
 [exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
                  ^   ^ 
 [exec] '/c'
        ^  ^
 [exec] '@for %a in (C:\src\ant\ant-dir-file-local) do @echo %~ta'
        ^                                                        ^
```

In this case, the single quotes (`'`) above each `^` aren't part of the command. Ant wraps the executable name and each argument with single quotes to make it clear what is part of the command and what isn't. Ant does this to help users debug their Ant scripts when `<exec>` doesn't behave as expected. The message is purely informational.

Comment: Ok but why do I get this error : The ' characters around the executable and arguments are not part of the command.   And the build finish without executing test to run ?!?  After the OpenAgent, it suppose to execute this :

Comment: <target name="run.test" depends="build, runJtfTests, launchOpenAgent">
<mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
<junit fork="no" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
<formatter type="xml" />
<test name="Silk4J.Automation.iControlSilk4J.com.miranda.icontrol.silk4j.installation.AdministrationCtrl" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <classpath refid="iControlSilk4J.classpath" >  </junit> /target>

Comment: Again, that's an informational message, not an error. To understand why the tests aren't running, please create a new question with the full Ant script and the output you get from Ant when you run Ant with the "-verbose" option.

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to wrap logged entries in single quotes so that if an entry is empty you can still see it, for example:

> No password for user ''

Otherwise you would see:

> No password for user

which is misleading.
In this case it only informs you that the quotes are only there for this reason and not part of the logged data. I think the sentence is slightly confusing because of the negative form 'are not part of the command' which looks like there is a problem...

Answer (score 0):

It is purely informative. It is there to indicate that the apostrophe (**'**) symbol you see above is not actually within the command that has been used.
It just "quotes" the string tokens you used in your command.

Example:

```
 [exec] Current OS is Windows 10
 [exec] Output redirected to property: git.timestamp
 [exec] Executing 'cmd.exe' with arguments:
 [exec] '/c'
 [exec] 'git'
 [exec] 'show'
 [exec] '-s'
 [exec] '--format=%ct'
 [exec]
 [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
 [exec] not part of the command.
```

This indicates that you used **/c git show -s --format=%ct** inside cmd, and you can see that from the **'/c'**, **'git'** tokens. It just tells you to ignore the **'** symbol. What it actually used is the git, show, -ss, etc. tokens in a chain, forming a full command.

Answer (score 0):

This is fallible information for ant. Please note, that this error will result in a returned status code of "1", exiting your build as failed. It is not merely "purely informative" as the previous poster has stated. This part of the java invoked Runtime.exec() methods which ant implements. Overrides include the parameters (String command, args[]), and also (String cmdLine).